# Number of photons

Tags: visible-light, photons

When a light source blinks, it "creates" a ball of photons, expanding by speed of light. How many photons are there in one "layer" of the ball (no matter how long is the source active)? Is it a definite number?

Thanks

Comment: It's going to depend on the light source

Comment: Define "layer", for one thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of photons may indeed be finite because the energy of the photon in ${\rm J}$ is 
$$ E = hf$$ 
where $h=6.626\times 10^{-34}{\rm J}\cdot {\rm s}$ is Planck's constant and $f$ is the frequency in ${\rm Hz}$. For monochromatic light, the number of photons may be determined from the energy in this simple way because $f$ is a fixed constant:
$$ N_{\rm photons} = \frac{E_{\rm total}}{hf} $$
For light that is a mixture of many frequencies, one has to separate the energy to the contributions from different frequencies, and apply the rule above separately for each frequency:
$$ N_{\rm photons} = \frac{1}{h} \int_0^\infty \frac{df}{f} \frac{dE}{df} $$
where $dE/df$ is the total energy per unit frequency as a function of the frequency. A problem in applying the formula above is that in many cases, the integral may be divergent around $f\to 0$, very tiny frequency limit. The "soft" photons of low frequencies carry an extremely low energy, and that's why it's easy to accumulate or emit or absorb big numbers of photons without transferring or spending too much energy. We talk about the "infrared divergences" if the number of photons is divergent around $f\to 0$.

Clearly, the number of photons is proportional to the time over which the light source is turned on, and the intensity (power) of the light source. The number of photons is a whole number – an integer – which means that the classical idea that the energy carried by light may be arbitrary or continuously change isn't accurate.

Comment: Thank you for a large explanation. Honestly, I don't fully understand those equations, but still I appreciate it!