# Number of photons in a range of wavelengths

Tags: photons, photoelectric-effect, photon-emission

I need to calculate the number of photons in a beam of light of power $P$. I know that it has constant power $P$ across the range of wavelengths $[\lambda_1,\lambda_2]$. So, for calculating this, I've used a formula that was given in another SE question:

$$N=\frac{1}{h} \int_{\nu_1}^{\nu_2} \frac{1}{\nu} \frac{dE}{d\nu} d\nu  $$

It's all fine, and using this I came up with $N=ln(\nu_2/\nu_1) $. But I'm not convinced completely on that formula because I'm not able to derive it from $E=N(\nu)h\nu$.

The answer I get from the formula seems right, but I need proof for that.

Source for the equation:
[Number of photons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/209937/number-of-photons?rq=1)

Comment: So what is the expression for $dE/d\nu$ you used to evaluate your integral?

Comment: Well, the power is evenly distributed across the interval, so I said $E=h\nu$, thus $dE/d\nu =h$

Comment: Why not $E=2h\nu$? There are many possibilities Why do you choose one specific one? The equation $E=h\nu$ is related to energy of a single photon. What if you do not have single-photon source? Even if your source is single photon. These things usually produce many thousands of single-photon pulses per second, so again, your choice for $E$ seems strange.

Comment: It's not that strange. I'm calculating the total number of photons emitted by the source, and they are evenly distributed. By this I mean the power is the same for every frequency in the range. So $E=h\nu$ should be the function I want. If not please correct me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power is the amount of energy conveyed per second, so you won't be able to compute the number of photons.  Instead, you will compute the number of photons per second.  I take $P$ to mean the total beam power within the frequency range from $\nu_1$ to $\nu_2$.

The number of photons per second in a small spectral interval $\delta\nu$ is going to depend on the ratio of beam power in that spectral interval, to the energy per photon in the spectral interval.

The power of the beam is equal to the number of photons per second, divided by the energy per photon. The photons have a range of frequencies, $\nu_1$ through $\nu_2$.  The problem states that the power is the same for each frequency within that range.

Let *N* be the total number of photons per second conveyed by the beam. Let's pick a small frequency range from $\nu_i$ to $\nu_i + \delta\nu$.  We can pretend all the photons in that small range have the same frequency, $\nu_i$.   So the number of photons per second in that range is $\delta\nu\frac{dP/d\nu}{h\nu_i}$.  But $dP/d\nu$ is a constant: $$dP/d\nu = P/(\nu_2-\nu_1)$$

To find the total number of photons per second in the whole range, we need to add up all the contributions from all the small ranges:

$$N (total photons/sec) = \frac{P}{\nu_2-\nu_1}\sum(\delta\nu\frac{1}{h\nu_i})$$

over all $\nu_i$ in the range.  That's just the integral

$$N= \frac{P}{\nu_2-\nu_1}\int_{\nu_1}^{\nu_2} \frac{1}{h\nu} d\nu$$

where $N$ is the number of *photons per second* within the range from $\nu_1$ to $\nu_2$.

(Hopefully I haven't made any errors in the math.  I'm very clumsy with MathJax.)

Comment: Thats fine, but what I wanted to know is the derivation for the formula. I mean, how do you get there  from $E=Nh\nu$?

Comment: $N$ in the formula I gave is *a number of photons per second*.  $N$ in $E = Nh\nu$ is a number of photons, not a number of photons per second.

Comment: Fine, then say $P=Nh\nu$ where $N$ is number oh photons per second. How do you derive the formula for $N$ when $\nu$ is an interval?

Comment: Ah so: you need to understand better what the integral means.  I will edit my answer to include that.

Comment: The edit made it so much clearer! But there is one last thing that bothers me... When you write the number of photons per second in the small range of frequencies, how do you get that? I can't seem to wrap my head around this idea. It is the only doubt I really had. From the start I know I should be integrating some function over $\nu$ but I could not get there. This crucial step is really bugging me, it sound very straight forward, but I feel like I'm missing a step.

Comment: There is some number N of photons per second in the beam, in the $ \nu_1 $ to $\nu_2$ range.  Per the problem statement, power is equal in each section of the spectrum, as long as the widths of the sections are the same. In any particular section, if the section is narrow enough,  there is (for practical purposes) only one frequency.  We know how much energy each photon of that frequency has, and so can divide that energy into the power associated with that section of the spectrum to obtain the number of photons per second in that section.