# Number of photons in range of frequencies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, photoelectric-effect

I was trying to calculate the number of photons emitted by a light of constant power $P$ between frequencies $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$. I have already checked this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/459467/number-of-photons-in-a-range-of-wavelengths?noredirect=1&lq=1) but the reply marked as correct asserts that $\dfrac{dP}{d\nu}$ is a constant and has a value of:

$$\dfrac{dP}{d\nu}=\dfrac{P}{\nu_2-\nu_1} $$

However, I cannot see where this result comes from. Shouldn't $\dfrac{dP}{d\nu}=0$ since $P$ is constant throughout $[\nu_1,\nu_2]$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $P$ is the *total power*. When they say, $dP$, they mean a portion of the power belonging to a frequency range $d\nu$. From $E=h\nu$, photons of different frequency would radiate with different power.

Now, just to explain what that formula in the question is:

$$\frac{dP}{d\nu} = \frac{P}{\nu_2 -\nu_1}$$Assume $P(\nu)$ or the power emitted along one frequency alone (i.e. power is a function of frequency, as we know it is). In fact, if you plotted a graph with the power on the y-axis and frequency on the x-axis, you get a straight line (as expected due to $E=hf$).

$$\frac{dP}{d\nu}=\frac{P(\nu_2)-P(\nu_1)}{\nu_2-\nu_1}$$
And you can see that $\int dP=P$. If you put the limits on this particular integral, you can see that the result is $P=P(\nu_2)-P(\nu_1)$.

Comment: I think I understand your reasoning, but I believe it does not agree with the fact that $P$ is constant throughout $[\nu_1,\nu_2]$. The exercise I am attempting to solve states that for any wave length between $[\lambda_2,\lambda_1$], power $P$ is constant. Moreover it includes a $P$ vs. $\lambda$ graph where you can see a horizontal line

Comment: If that were the case, then $dP/d\nu = 0$. The question you have linked and your is very different then

Comment: But I don't understand how it can be so: then the only possible explanation for such a power $P$ for every single frequency is if the intensity varies. But how is that really possible?

Comment: The question _asked_ was the same as yours. But the answer given that was accepted, assumes $P$ to be the _total power of the beam across the range of wavelengths $[\lambda_1,\lambda_2]$_

Comment: Actually I cannot understand the situation either. That is why I decided to search some information here and found the answer I linked, and that answer only contributed more to my confusion

Comment: I think there must have been a misunderstanding. The power (or simply the energy contributed per second) is not the same across every single frequency. It seems to me, as I have written in my answer, that $P$ is only the total beam power across all the frequencies (or simply the total energy radiated per second). It seems more likely to me.

Comment: Saying $dP$ is not incorrect, as we are assuming a fraction $dP$ of the entire radiated $P$. And $\int dP=P$. That's how you probably would like to relate.